# Cannot connect to local ip address after windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10

I have an application that connects to a device via TCP. I have an emulator for that device that runs on the same pc as the application. The application connects to the emulator via the local ip address. Before the windows 10 upgrade I could perform this connection on any local ip address 127.x.x.x - after the upgrade only the local ip address 127.0.0.1 will work.

This is a problem as I require multiple emulators running each on a different local ip address.

What settings do I need to change to allow this behaviour to occur as before the upgrade?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. What is your exact Windows version?

Comment: Most cases firewall block it. Check your firewall and emulator settings

Comment: windows 10 enterprise version 1709 - There is every chance it wont be easily repeatable as I imagine it will be an obscure setting somewhere... Maybe firewall - but I should have the same firewall as a colleague for whom this does work...